# Error when running app from Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

Tags: ios, xcode, xlpagertabstrip

When running the app from Xcode Version 9.0 beta 4 (9M189t), everything works fine. But when I run the same code on Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b), the app crashes with this message:

```
PagerTabViewController in Interface Builder file.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x12e51aac0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key leftBarButtonItem.'
```

On interface builder I can see that 'leftBarButtonItem' is correctly linked with the button.

[image]

The connection inspector shows this:

[image]

It doesn't show problem on 'leftBarButtonItem', but yes it shows problems for 'buttonBarView' and 'containerView'.

These two items are from pod XLPagerTabStrip. These two items must be connected in interface builder in order to work. I don't know if my problem is related with this pod, but it's weird these connections shows problems. As I said, on Xcode 9.0 it shows correctly and runs without errors. I tried to disconnect these two views and connect again, but when I do it the interface builder don't let me connect it again.

I'm completely lost with this problem. I need to use Xcode 8.3.3 in order to upload a binary to App Store.

Xcode 9.0 uses Swift 4 as compiler while Xcode 8.3.3 uses Swift 3.1. I also don't know if this is the problem.

Any idea about what is happening? Thanks

Comment: Probably unrelated but why are you still using beta 4? The GM version of Xcode 9 came out yesterday. Always use the latest, especially when using beta versions.

Comment: It worked. Thanks